# How can I get the directory from a script called by another script in python via a function imported

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my problem; I have a main script that imports my own package which contains a function that returns the current directory of my the script which is running. There is no problem when the main script calls this function because he is the one which calls the function and the os.getcwd() works well. However, i've another script which is called by this main script via exec() and when i try to get the directory via the function of my package, it gives me the directory of my main script (because it just adds the code of my other script to my main script). So I finally tried to use subprocess but i've the same problem. (Maybe because it does not import a second time my package, i don't know). I've tried others solutions like the use of  `filename = inspect.getframeinfo(inspect.currentframe()).filename
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(filename))` but it gives me the package's path and not the script's path
Does anyone have a solution to solve my problem ?
I've attached a diagram to illustrate my problem.
Thanks in advance
[My Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZYxE.png)

Comment: [`os.getcwd`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd) does not return the location of any script, it returns your current working directory, that is, the directory from where the main script was called (which may or may not be the same directory where it lives). Subprocesses inherit the working directory of the parent process, so you get the same result unless you do [`os.chdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir). You need to use `__file__` or call `inspect.currentframe()` in the script which path you want to find.